# slick carousel doesn't work in rtl direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

I work with slick carousel for show testimonial carousel in `rtl` direction like this:

Html:

```
<div class="testimonial-area">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="testimonial-image-slider slider-nav text-center">
              <div class="sin-testiImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/3F6881/000">
              </div>
              <div class="sin-testiImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/D09D8C/000">
              </div>
              <div class="sin-testiImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/FEDD31/000">
              </div>
              <div class="sin-testiImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/EEBE74/000">
              </div>
              <div class="sin-testiImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/313130/fff">
              </div>
              <div class="sin-testiImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/D09D8C/000">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-text-slider slider-for text-center">
          <div class="sin-testiText">
            <h2>Shabab Ahmed </h2>
            <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="sin-testiText">
            <h2>Soyong Sourav</h2>
            <p>Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt This lorem is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean nisi sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum gravida.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="sin-testiText">
            <h2>Joker Buzz</h2>
            <p>Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean tincidunt sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum Photoshop.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="sin-testiText">
            <h2>M S Nawaz </h2>
            <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="sin-testiText">
            <h2>Chowchilla Madera</h2>
            <p>Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, aliquet lorem quis tellus velit bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum</p>
          </div>
          <div class="sin-testiText">
            <h2>Kattie Luis</h2>
            <p>Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem gravida tincidunt quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  unicode-bidi: embed !important;
}

.testimonial-area {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 95px 0 82px;
  position: relative;
}
.testimonial-area:after {
  background: rgba(45, 62, 80, 0.9) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.testimonial-image-slider {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.slick-list {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.sin-testiImage {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  outline: medium none;
}
.sin-testiImage img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block !important;
  height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 36px;
  outline: 0 none;
  width: 80px;
}
.sin-testiImage.slick-current img {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  height: 146px;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  width: 146px;
}
.testimonial-text-slider h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: "montserratregular";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.testimonial-text-slider {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 51%;
  z-index: 9;
}
.sin-testiText {
  outline: none;
}
.sin-testiText p {
  margin-top: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 25px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34.6%;
  width: 16px;
}
.slick-prev {
  left: -31px;
}
.slick-next {
  right: -31px;
}
.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  height: 25px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  content: "";
  font-family: "Material-Design-Iconic-Font";
  font-size: 50px !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
.slick-next:before {
  right: 0;
  content: "";
}
.slick-slider {
  z-index: 9;
}
.testimonial-area:hover .slick-prev:before,
.testimonial-area:hover .slick-next:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}
```

JS:

```
$(".slider-for").slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  draggable: false,
  fade: true,
  rtl:true,
  asNavFor: ".slider-nav"
});
$(".slider-nav").slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: ".slider-for",
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  rtl:true,
  centerPadding: "10px",
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 450,
      settings: {
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        centerPadding: "0px"
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 420,
      settings: {
        autoplay: true,
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        centerMode: false
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

No In action after add `rtl:true` js and add `direction:rtl` to css carousel not work true. I see two problem:

**first**: carousel text not show!!
**second**: after click in image, select image not show in center.

how do fix this problems?

[Demo Here](https://codepen.io/alakian/pen/PoZqYXe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix it:

add `dir="rtl"` to `<div class="testimonial-area" dir="rtl">`

Answer (score 0):

it works for me (add style to your slick slider main div) if not working plase add   let survey = {
rtl: true,
};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).